# Open source tools for implementing machine learning algorithm on FPGA

Tags: machine-learning, fpga, hardware-acceleration, conv-neural-network

Is there any open source tools/programs available for implementing machine learning algorithms like CNN on FPGA fabric?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using high level synthesis for what you are trying to do. It is not open source, but for example Vivado HLS comes freely with the [Vivado WebPACK](https://www.xilinx.com/products/design-tools/vivado/vivado-webpack.html). You can write your code in C/C++, generate the HDL code, co-simulate and optimize it all through the tool in a very short time.

I see that there are some projects for machine learning (e.g. [hls4ml](https://hls-fpga-machine-learning.github.io/hls4ml/)) which seem to be currently in development, but might be worth checking out.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response @zesen. The problems with HLS is that you don't know the quality of the generated code in the Verilog. Most often the level of control - like the multiple clock domain, asynchronous reset, pipelining with advanced controls - are lost in HLS style coding.

The hls4ml provide better ways to fix (to help us use the right pragmas) the HLS c/c++ code but the problem still remains.